# Confusion Matrix gives different results from Keras predict

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, predict, confusion-matrix

I have trained a neural network to recognize static images of signs from the alphabet of sign language.

After training, I tried to evaluate its performance using the Keras predict function:

```
def predict_img(img, img_width, img_height, model):
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam'  ,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.load_weights(weights_name)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height)) 
    img = img/255.0
    img = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)
    pred = model.predict(img, batch_size= 1, verbose=1)
    classes = np.argmax(pred)
    return classes
```

Basically what I do is I call the predict on the input image and return the index of the class with the highest probability.
I then called this function on every image of the test folder, checking whether the prediction is correct or not. To do this, I compared the prediction of the model with the first character of the filename (which is the letter corresponding to that sign).
I counted all the correct predictions in order to calculate the percentage of correct predictions over all the test images.
Here is the code:

```
#Read the image with OpenCV
images = []
total_cases = 0
correct_predictions = 0
for dir in os.listdir(folder):  
    for filename in os.listdir(folder+"/"+dir):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder+"/"+dir,filename))
        pred = predict_img(img, img_width, img_height, model)
        total_cases = total_cases + 1
        # if prediction is correct
        if sign_labels[pred] == filename[0]:
            correct_predictions = correct_p + 1

print(correct_predictions, " correct prediction on", c , "total tests")
print((correct_predictions * 100) / c, "%", "success on ", folder)
```

However, this way, the results are pretty low (around 50%).

I then used the confusion matrix to evaluate the performance of the model:

```
# CONFUSION MATRIX
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(testing_generator, nb_validation_samples // 64 + 1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
cm = confusion_matrix(testing_generator.classes, y_pred)
print(cm)
print('Classification Report')

print(classification_report(testing_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=sign_labels))
```

And I get the following results:

```
Confusion Matrix
[[ 3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  9  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  4  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9]]

Classification Report
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          a       0.75      1.00      0.86         3
          b       1.00      1.00      1.00         4
          c       1.00      1.00      1.00         4
          d       1.00      1.00      1.00         4
          e       1.00      1.00      1.00         9
          f       1.00      1.00      1.00         6
          h       1.00      1.00      1.00         7
          i       1.00      1.00      1.00        10
          k       0.67      0.80      0.73         5
          l       1.00      1.00      1.00         5
          m       1.00      0.88      0.93         8
          n       1.00      1.00      1.00         7
          o       1.00      1.00      1.00         5
          p       1.00      0.75      0.86         8
          q       0.89      1.00      0.94         8
          r       0.83      0.83      0.83        12
          t       1.00      1.00      1.00         9
          u       0.82      0.82      0.82        11
          v       1.00      0.80      0.89         5
          w       1.00      1.00      1.00         8
          x       0.88      1.00      0.93         7
          y       1.00      1.00      1.00         9

avg / total       0.95      0.94      0.94       154
```

My questions are:

- Is it normal that I get such different results form the Confusion Matrix and Keras' predict? Am I using the Keras predict wrong?
- The Confusion Matrix results vary a little bit each time I execute the script, is this normal as well?
- Can the Confusion Matrix give skewed results?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here are the generators:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

testing_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    folder,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Whats `testing_generator`? Without your whole code, we cant help much

Comment: I edited the original post with the generators

Comment: Did you compare the output of your generator with the images you load manually? You should get the same results with the same inputs. So it is likely that the images you input are somehow different.